# Metal LB In Kind Cluster does not Work as per documentation on MacOS

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kind

I Followed all the steps in MacOS https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/loadbalancer/

but i could not create a external load balancer

```
% LB_IP=$(kubectl get svc/foo-service -o=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')

% curl ${LB_IP}:5678 -v
*   Trying 172.19.255.201:5678...
* connect to 172.19.255.201 port 5678 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to 172.19.255.201 port 5678 after 75006 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.19.255.201 port 5678 after 75006 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: Are there any firewall running on the node where metallb loadbalancer is running ? Are you blocking port 5678 ?

Comment: Also 172.19.255.201 is a private ip address within your network. Are you trying to access this from internet ?

Comment: should try on Ubuntu and update here